# May one play music for a baby during the Omer?

Tags: music, sefirat-ha-omer, children

2-year-olds love to listen to recorded nursery rhymes. Are there any sources discussing playing nursery rhymes that include background music during the omer?

Answer (score 2):

Once can play such music for children(who have not reached chinuch age).

Nitei Gavriel 3:53

Text:

[image]

Comment: Great source! An English-language summary of the text would be very useful for many users